# rs485 network - strange issue

Tags: php, ruby, linux, rs485

It is not an issue, but if someone can help?

I wrote some driver for smartcard readers (in PHP) that communicates in a rs485 network.
It works fine with 1 - 7 readers while connection cable was short, but when I start deploying it on the network, I notice than it causes too much noise and the driver is not able to work.

In php I used 'stty' linux console command to set up serial port for further actions. I also have Ruby code, which can work only with one reader.

**Question**: when I launch the ruby script, wait for 10 seconds, kill the Ruby process and then launch the PHP driver, it works perfectly:  no noise.
When I run the PHP *without* running the ruby script first: it does not work...

I know about RS network standards and other things like addresses of devices, broadcasting, noise reduction, e.g

The network was build with 3 contacts: RX, TX and GND.
In PHP I used addresses of readers. In Ruby a broadcast (0xFF)
Some addresses in the network are restricted - I avoid them.

Comment: sorry, brodccast - 0xFF - not 0x00

Comment: Maybe your ruby code does some port configuration which isn’t done by php code? Like parity bit settings for example.

Comment: i try diferent settings in stty command, - in ruby all settings by default - it is wery simple code - writed to test possibility of ruby lib for ftdi readers, and all works fine with php only untill we start using longer cable...